# What is JedaiLib-0.2.swc?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, red5, swc

I found that Eclipse IDE for red5 generates sample client SWF code which is using JedaiLib-0.2.swc as a library. All actual code is hidden inside this file.

Where did this file come from? Who wrote it? Is it possible to obtain it's sources or documentation? Where?

**URL**

Also the source is here: http://code.google.com/p/jedai/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation could be found at

http://labs.emoten.com/googlecode/jedai/docs/html/